# Convert csv file having pixel values into images

Tags: python, image, csv

I have a [csv file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aqdq5f4fhNTWbKlht3OW8ARAS7N5u3DO), in which each row contains the pixel values for an image. Therefore, each column of a row contains pixel values, except for the last column, which contains the 'labels' for the image, which are words such as "coat", "dress", "sandal" etc. (Note: First row contains the column names and is not an image).

I wish to read these rows as images and save all of them (preferably sorted by label, such as 'dress1', 'dress2',....,'sandal1', 'sandal2',.., etc. for each of the four labels).

I tried the following approach for saving without label classification, but I am getting an error:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
i=0
with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
      for data in csv.reader(csv_file):
      pixels = data[:]
      pixels = np.array(pixels, dtype='uint8')
      #Reshape the array into 28 x 28 array (As images are 28x28)
      pixels = pixels.reshape((28, 28)) 
      i +=1
      plt.savefig(str(i))
```

Looking for the most efficient way to go about this. Any inputs will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There's a syntax error after your for loop here. Is it the original code? Also, post the error that you are getting

Comment: are you plotting the data or creating an image?

Comment: if you have name in last column then you have to convert without last element `data[:-1]`. And use last column as a nam `savefig( data[-1] + str(i) + '.jpg' )`. Without extension it may not know what type of image write.

Comment: you would have to count `i` for every label separatelly - ie. using dict - `i = dict()` `i[label] = 0` `i[label] += 0` `savefig( label + str(i[label]) + '.jpg' )`

Comment: I checked file and pixels are not integer values but float numbers (positive and negative) so you can't use `uint8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have name in last column then you have to convert without last element `data[:-1]`. And use last column in filenamename `savefig( data[-1] + str(i) + '.jpg' )`. Without extension it may not know what type of image to write.

You have to count `i` for every label separatelly - ie. using dict

```
i = dict() 
i[label] = 0 

# later 

i[label] += 1 
savefig( label + str(i[label]) + '.jpg'
```

You can also use `PIL`/'pillow`instead of`matplotlib` to write it.

```
from PIL import Image    

image = Image.fromarray(pixels)
image.save(filename)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from PIL import Image    

counter = dict()

with open('myfile.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    # skip headers
    next(csv_reader)

    for row in csv.reader(csv_reader):

        pixels = row[:-1] # without label
        pixels = np.array(pixels, dtype='uint8')
        pixels = pixels.reshape((28, 28))
        image = Image.fromarray(pixels)

        label = row[-1]

        if label not in counter:
            counter[label] = 0
        counter[label] += 1

        filename = '{}{}.jpg'.format(label, counter[label])
        image.save(filename)

        print('saved:', filename)
```

---

**EDIT:** Example which show it with one row of data for those which whan to test it without downloading csv file.

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from PIL import Image

counter = dict()

row = [
        255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  255,
          0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,    0,
          0, 255,   0, 255,   0, 255,    0,
          0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,    0,
          0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255,    0,
          0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,    0,
        255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  255,
        'face'
      ]

pixels = row[:-1]

pixels = np.array(pixels, dtype='uint8')
pixels = pixels.reshape((7, 7))
image = Image.fromarray(pixels)

label = row[-1]

if label not in counter:
    counter[label] = 0
counter[label] += 1

filename = '{}{}.png'.format(label, counter[label])

image.save(filename)

print('saved:', filename)
```

Result: `face1.png`:

[image]

---

**EDIT:** I checked your csv file and pixels are not integer values but float (positive, negative) values so you can't use `uint8`. It has to be `float`.

```
pixels = np.array(pixels, dtype='float')
```

You could convert image to `RGB` or grayscale `L` to save it

```
image = image.convert('RGB')
image = image.convert('L')
```

but it seems it has problem to convert negative values.

Using

```
plt.imsave(filename, pixels)
```

I get expected result

---

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from PIL import Image    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

counter = dict()

with open('gen_image_wgan.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    # skip headers
    next(csv_reader)

    for row in csv_reader:

        pixels = row[:-1] # without label
        pixels = np.array(pixels, dtype='float')
        pixels = pixels.reshape((28, 28))

        label = row[-1]

        if label not in counter:
            counter[label] = 0
        counter[label] += 1

        filename = '{}{}.png'.format(label, counter[label])
        plt.imsave(filename, pixels)

        print('saved:', filename)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really detailed and insightful! Great code, @furas !

Comment: If this was a csv file containing RGB images, would there be a change? Would we reshape in pixels.reshape() differently?

Comment: if original image is 28x28 then reshaping will give broken image - you wouldn't see coat or dress on image.  And it doesn't matter if it is RGB or grayscale.