# Converting a csv file containing pixel values to it's equivalent images

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is my first time working with such a dataset.
I have a .csv file containing pixel values (48x48 = 2304 columns) of images, with their labels in the first column and the pixels in the subsequent ones, as below:

[A glimpse of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnzI2.png)

I want to convert these pixels into their images, and store them into different directories corresponding to their respective labels. Now I have tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447219/convert-csv-file-having-pixel-values-into-images#) but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here's what I've tried to do:

```
labels = ['Fear', 'Happy', 'Sad']

with open('dataset.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    fear = 0
    happy = 0
    sad = 0

# skip headers
    next(csv_reader)

    for row in csv_reader:

        pixels = row[1:] # without label
        pixels = np.array(pixels, dtype='uint8')
        pixels = pixels.reshape((48, 48))
        image = Image.fromarray(pixels)

        if csv_file['emotion'][row] == 'Fear':
            image.save('C:\\Users\\name\\data\\fear\\im'+str(fear)+'.jpg')
            fear += 1

        elif csv_file['emotion'][row] == 'Happy':
            image.save('C:\\Users\\name\\data\\happy\\im'+str(happy)+'.jpg')
            happy += 1
    
        elif csv_file['emotion'][row] == 'Sad':
            image.save('C:\\Users\\name\\data\\sad\\im'+str(sad)+'.jpg')
            sad += 1
```

However, upon running the above block of code, the following is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-aa928099f061>", line 18, in <module>
    if csv_file['emotion'][row] == 'Fear':

TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

I referred to a bunch of posts that solved the above error ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977477/typeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-is-not-subscriptable)), but I found that the people were trying their hand at a relatively different problem than mine, and others I couldn't understand.
This may well be a very trivial question, but as I mentioned earlier, this is my first time working with such a dataset. Kindly tell me what am I doing wrong and how I can fix my code.

Comment: Always provide a [mre], with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text**, not screenshots, because [SO Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/). It is likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**.

Comment: I've solved this. Thank you for your input - I shall keep those points in mind the next time I ask a question here. (Although barring the screenshot of the dataset, my question had everything you mentioned, I'd like to think.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem that arose was that the first row was just the column names. In order to take care of this, I used the `skiprows` parameter like so:

`raw = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', skiprows = 1)`

Secondly, I moved the labels column to the end due to it being in the first column. For my own convenience.

Thirdly, after all the preparations were done, the dataset won't iterate over the whole row, and instead just took in the value of the first row and first column, which gave an issue in resizing. So I instead used the `df.itertuples()` like so:

`for row in data.itertuples(index = False, name = 'Pandas'):`

Lastly, thanks to @HadarM 's suggestions, I was able to get it to work.

Modified code of the above code snippet that was the problematic block:

```
for row in data.itertuples(index = False, name = 'Pandas'):

    pixels = row[:-1] # without label
    pixels = np.array(pixels, dtype='uint8')
    pixels = pixels.reshape((48, 48))
    image = Image.fromarray(pixels)

    if str(row[-1]) == 'Fear':
        image.save('C:\\Users\\name\\data\\fear\\im'+str(fear)+'.jpg')
        fear += 1

    elif str(row[-1]) == 'Happy':
        image.save('C:\\Users\\name\\data\\happy\\im'+str(happy)+'.jpg')
        happy += 1
    
    elif str(row[-1]) == 'Sad':
        image.save('C:\\Users\\name\\data\\sad\\im'+str(sad)+'.jpg')
        sad += 1

print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
if str(row[0]) == 'Fear':
```

And in a similar way for the other conditions:

```
elif str(row[0]) == 'Happy':
elif str(row[0]) == 'Sad':
```

(a good practice is to just save the first value of the array as a variable)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Though it wasn't the complete thing, it did help tons! I've upvoted it but due to rep<15 it won't show.